# Helm - using global values by default

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Helm.

I have a default value in parent chart. I want to use this value in each subchart by default, but also to have a possibility to override the value for a specific subchart.

Example:

```
# Parent-chart values.yaml

global:
  schedule: 10m
```

All the subcharts will use this value by default. But if I run something like this:

```
helm install --set subchart-A.schedule="20m"
```

Subchart-A will use value "20m".

I'm thinking about two possibilities:

1. Maybe I can somehow link subchart-value to global value:

```
# Subchart values.yaml

schedule: {{ .Values.global.schedule }} # it doesn't work
```

In that case, it would be possible to override a specific value for the single subchart.

2. Maybe I can write a function

```
# Pseudocode:

if subchart.schedule is null
  printf global.schedule
else
  printf subchart.schedule
```

What would you do and what is generally possible?

Comment: Can you use `default`? something like `{{ .Values.global.schedule | default subchart-A.schedule }}` https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_template_guide/variables/

Comment: Values yaml files cannot take variables. So, option 1 is ruled out. As you have mentioned, option 2 is the better option.

Comment: @hmatt1, thank you, it does exactly what I need (but upside down, global is default).Unfortunately it is not clear in documentation.
You can add it as an answer, then I would close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/) for reference.

You can specify defaults!

Example from the docs:

```
{{- with .Values.favorite }}
drink: {{ .drink | default "tea" | quote }}
food: {{ .food | upper | quote }}
release: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- end }}
```

In your case, it would be something like:

```
{{ subchart-A.schedule | default .Values.global.schedule }}
```

Comment: ```{{ subchart-A.schedule | default .Values.global.schedule }}```
With above option still we wont be able to render or run subchart it gives with error mentioning  at <.Values.global.schedule>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.schedule

Comment: @RajuRh it might be different for you. What is in your `values.yaml` ? If you look at the question, they were working with this:

global:
  schedule: 10m

Comment: Parent chart has value like 
`
global:
  schedule: 40`

Subchart value file 

`
schedule: 30
`

Config map for subchart contains 
  Test1:  "{{ .Values.schedule | default .Values.global.schedule }}"

Now if I try to do helm template on subchart it gives error.